# Anaconda Python to EXE with Pyinstaller - huge binary and slow execution

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm in the process of attempting to convert a Python script to compiled exe to allow me distribute to a number of clients.  I have never attempted this before, so am unsure over what to expect regarding size of the distributed files etc.

An example (cut down) version of the script is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


group_size=[10]
subgroup_size=[10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10]

a, b, c, d,e,f,g,h,i =[plt.cm.Blues,plt.cm.Blues,plt.cm.Blues, plt.cm.Reds,plt.cm.Reds,plt.cm.Reds, plt.cm.Greens,plt.cm.Greens,plt.cm.Greens]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.axis('equal')
mypie, _ = ax.pie(group_size, radius=3, colors= [a(0.90)],startangle=90 )
plt.setp( mypie, width=0.5, edgecolor='black')

# Second Ring (Inside)
mypie2, _ = ax.pie(subgroup_size, radius=3-0.5,  colors=[a(.9), b(0.2), c(0.2),d(.2),e(.2),f(.2),g(.9),h(.2),i(.2)],startangle=90,counterclock=False)
plt.setp( mypie2, width=0.5, edgecolor='black')
plt.margins(0,0)

mypie3, _ = ax.pie(subgroup_size, radius=3-1.0,  colors=[a(.9), b(0.8), c(0.6),d(.2),e(.6),f(.2),g(.9),h(.7),i(.2)],startangle=90,counterclock=False)
plt.setp( mypie3, width=0.5, edgecolor='black')
plt.margins(0,0)

mypie4, _ = ax.pie(subgroup_size, radius=3-1.5, colors=[a(.9), b(0.8), c(0.6),d(.2),e(.6),f(.4),g(.9),h(.7),i(.5)],startangle=90,counterclock=False)
plt.setp( mypie4, width=0.5, edgecolor='black')
plt.margins(0,0)

mypie5, _ = ax.pie(subgroup_size, radius=3-2,  colors=[a(.9), b(0.8), c(0.6),d(.8),e(.6),f(.4),g(.9),h(.7),i(.5)],startangle=90,counterclock=False)
plt.setp( mypie5, width=0.5, edgecolor='black')
plt.margins(0,0)

mypie6, _ = ax.pie(subgroup_size, radius=0.5,  colors=[a(.999)],startangle=90,counterclock=False)
plt.setp( mypie6, width=0.9, edgecolor=a(0.999))
plt.margins(0,0)

# show it
plt.show()
```

It doesn't do anything clever - draws a nested pie chart as per the screen shot [image]

Using Pyinstaller with "Pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --clean wheel.py"  this compiles successfully to an executable Windows binary as can be seen in the second screenshot.  [image]

However, the binary is 330Mb in size and takes about 20 seconds to load / start.  (I appreciate that the exe is rolling up the Python interpreter - so the size might be what it is)

My question(s):

(1) Is there a "better" (ie smaller binary / quicker load) way to do this?  (Am I missing something)
(2) Is there a "better" way to deploy an application written in Python?

(I am using Python as I am using matplotlib extensively to generate modified nested pie charts and this has proved to be the most reliable).  Sadly, I can't get my clients to install Python -- a single file install is the lowest barrier to entry.

Any pointers greatly received.

Edit:
So it transpires that the file size is dictated by the Python interpreter - the same binary size is created create my own GUI using TKinter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears that the "issue" is compiling into a single file.  This is unpacked every time the exe file is executed.  So, removing --onefile speeds the execution.  Now I need an installer file!!